# How to check if cygwin mintty/bash is run as administrator?

Tags: windows, bash, terminal, cygwin

**Problem Statement:** What is the most elegant and robust way to test if Cygwin `mintty` `bash` session is "Run as adminstrator"?

**Why, specifically?** I have typically several `mintty` terminals open when using Windows (`mintty` does not have  tabs). The most awkward is when I need to find a terminal window that I started by right-clicking "Run as administrator" when for example I want to run `ping` or other one-time procedure. I would like to indicate the "run as administrator"-ness of the terminal session visually (by changing the `bash` shell prompt variable `PS1` in my start-up file `~/.bashrc`).

**Some quick potential solutions:**

1. I can compare the value of some environmental variables. By quick look of `env` output there are quite many differences. It is however hard to tell which is most reliable in terms of portability to another Windows machine (perhaps running different version of Windows).
2. `id`, more specifically `id -Gn` shows different groups if run as administrator. In my Windows 7 machine I have `Administrators` and `root` groups added to the list. Again, I am not sure if this is portable.
3. I could try to write a file to a location that would fail as normal user. *But I do not want to write any files to strange places - this could in some imagined scenarios be potentially destructive (e.g. failing storage media) and this seems utterly inelegant to my taste.*
4. Running some Windows program that will indicate by return status or output if the command is run "as administrator". Best would be some with analogous purpose to that of  UNIX [`id(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/id.1.html) command (but natively existing in Windows - or Cygwin, but without too far fetched translation of Windows system concepts to POSIX emulated concepts).

Any better or more elegant suggestions? Perhaps cygwin provides a command utility dedicated for this purpose?

**Update:** 97% duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051883/batch-script-how-to-check-for-admin-rights/ - the difference is just here using `bash` instead of (IMHO weird and archaic) Windows `cmd.exe`. Please do check the answers and commentaries there.

Comment: use the "run as Administrator" unless you do this then the process is not elevated to Administrator permissions even if an Administrator account starts the process.  **Just create a shortcut so this is always done.**

Comment: @Ramhound Of course. But my problem is not how to run as administrator, my problem is how to detect in scriptable way if I am running as administrator. (I just recently had five terminals open, and needed to find the one that I run as administrator so that I could successfully run `ping`.)

Comment: @Ramhound If you had read my (overly verbose?) question, you would have been shocked already three times! Just I am not sure if the two methods (2 and 3; forget the method 1, attempting to create a file to some more protected location) are portable, and I am craving for something more elegant.

Comment: I did read your question.  I don't consider any of those possible solutions as being acceptable.  I would just create a shortcut and call it a day.

Comment: I recommend trying [ConEmu](http://conemu-maximus5.googlecode.com/). It has tabs, can run tab as administrator indicated by different icon in tabbar and most importantly uses console behind the scenes so native windows applications work on it correctly unlike on mintty.

Comment: @Ramhound So you imply the presence of `Administrators` group is not standard and portable way to distinguish if running as adminstrator in Windows? (Above when saying "group" I am using the concept of cygwin emulation layer, I am not sure what the Microsoft term is for this `Adminstrators`.) I would like to learn more about this.

Comment: @Ramhound You are right that my original problem (distinguishing the administrator terminal window) that I already had narrowed down into this question could be solved by making a short cut for `mintty` that 1. runs as administrator, 2. uses different configuration file with differing color settings and 3. uses an alternative icon. If you describe to general public how to create this, I will give you an upvote (unless you say in your answer that it cannot be done within a script :-).

Comment: @JanHudec That `ConEmu` sounds wonderful. Some time ago I tried searching something similar but could not quite find one. Thanks so much for the tip. I am definitively going to try it out.

Comment: @FooF - Just because you run a process with an Administrator level user does not mean the process itself has been escalated.  Windows by default will only esclate a process if the user approves of such action hence the "run as Administrator" feature in Windows.  You can also provider ALL permissions to ANY group you want even the `Foo` user group if you wanted.

Comment: @Ramhound Interesting. I have a strong Unix/Linux background but I am quite a newbie/stranger in Windows world. But this increasingly interesting conversation is perhaps a little bit out of scope in superuser.com. Maybe I should search/ask stackoverflow.com for advice where I could study the central concepts that the Windows GUI and help files so hard tries to obfuscate with its labyrinths of mouse clicking pathways and step-by-step instructions that make it difficult to see the forest from the trees and branches and leaves. :-)

Comment: @FooF - Just think it as `sudo` which is required even if you are running as a root user.

Comment: @Ramhound Weird, but charmingly so.

Comment: @Foof : If I understand you correctly, you want to see whether you run under elevated privileges, right? In this case, [here](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_elevation.php)  are a few ways. As far I can tell, the solution which uses `OPENFILES` should work well from Cygwin bash too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just wrote this function for the same reason.  I never know which shell has admin privileges.

```
function isadmin()
{
    net session > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo "admin"
    else echo "user"; fi
}
```

It adapted from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11995662/307968 for windows cmd shell.   Net Session returns 0 status if you are admin.

Now I just need to change my prompt, or maybe the titlebar color....

Comment: Nice find. Though there seems to be edge cases where this too fail, if you check the stackoverflow comments.

Comment: Nevertheless I accepted this answer because it points to a much comprehensive discussions (the stackoverflow question and the accepted answer there currently have scores of 147 and  255, respectively).

Comment: Thanks! I use this to selectively color the username in my prompt. If the sell is elevated, I color it red, otherwise green. Useful to keep track of which shells are elevated if you have many terminal windows open.

Comment: This work well for `MINGW64` used by `Git Bash` on Windows.

Comment: @FooF These questions and answers have multiple comments. Which one mentions the edge cases where this will fail?

Comment: @DanielKaplan - The mentioned answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11995662/307968 commentary mentions many edge cases. I am not positioned to help you with this as I am not using Windows at the moment and definitively not using multiple different versions of Windows.

Comment: @FooF To clarify, I was only looking for the link. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 20):

The definitive answer to this question comes from the [Cygwin mailing list](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2015-02/msg00057.html).  A process is running with Administrator rights if the user who started it is part of group 544 (Administrators). Also from the comment below by Cromax, it seems that group 114 (Local account and member of Administrator group) is also sometimes present. The test for these two groups is

```
id -G | grep -qE '\<(114|544)\>'
```

or in bash without external calls,

```
[[ "${GROUPS[@]}" =~ (^| )(114|544)( |$) ]]
```

For example,

```
id -G | grep -qE '\<(114|544)\>' && echo admin || echo user
```

In the past you also needed to check for group 0, the root group in /etc/group. But /etc/group is no longer installed in Cygwin, and should usually be removed if it's present, so it's [no longer recommended](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2016-03/msg00260.html) to check for group 0 too.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in Mingw/Msys. Steven's answer does, although only on Windows 7.

Comment: I've just tried that (on W7) and it didn't work, but I've noticed, that if Window's user one is logged as is also an administrator, then when when Cygwin is ran as administrator, there is another group that pops in `id`'s output, namely 114 (Local account and member of Administrator group). So the regexp should be updated to: `id -G | grep -qE '\<(114|544)\>' && echo admin || echo user`

Comment: Thanks. I haven't seen that myself, but I see that group 114 does seem to be an Administrators group, so it seems reasonable to check for it too. I revised the answer.

Answer (score 7):

I use the return value of the Windows program `at`.  I also recreated the functionality of the PROMPTING special character `\$`.

```
# Set a white $ initially
eStyle='\[\e[0m\]$'

# If 'at' succeeds, use a red # instead
at &> /dev/null && eStyle='\[\e[0;31m\]#\[\e[0m\]'  # Use # in red

PS1='\n\[\e[0;32m\]\u@\h \[\e[0;33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n'"$eStyle "
```

[image: Examples]

Comment: Assuming there is no equivalent of UNIX `id` command in Windows, I accept this as a correct answer. At least running `at` command without any arguments does not appear to have any side effects. I am going to use this method in my `.bashrc` file from now on! Thanks for the hack.

Comment: doesn't seem to work on windows8.1

Comment: @zzapper Please be more specific.  What happens / doesn't happen?  Error messages?

Comment: id returns same values,  at is deprecated use schtasks.exe instead but this works whether admin or not

Comment: Win 10: `The AT command has been deprecated. Please use schtasks.exe instead.` I'm not sure how to achieve the same outcome with the latter.

Answer (score 2):

Do something that only admin could do and test for success or fail:-

```
if touch c:/Users/.x ; then  echo 'ok'  ; fi
```

or

```
touch c:/Users/.x && echo ok
```

or

```
touch c:/Users/.x && \rm c:/Users/.x && echo ok
```

or

```
touch c:/Users/.x  &> /dev/null && \rm c:/Users/.x && echo you are admin
```

Answer (score 2):

`id -G | grep -qE '\<(544|0)\>'` didn't seem to work for me, as my output had neither <> or 544 even when elevated. However, since elevation is required for writing to `%WINDIR%\system32`, I used that to test for elevation with a shell function:

```
is_elevated() { 
   [[ $(uname -o) -eq "Cygwin" ]] || return 1
   touch $WINDIR/system32/.cyg_elevated &> /dev/null
}
```

When applied to Steven's excellent idea of a red hash character:

```
is_elevated && PS1='\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\[\e[0;31m\]#\[\e[0m\] '
```

Answer (score 1):

In Msys on Windows try this (I found the accepted answer didn't work in Msys)

`at &> /dev/null && echo "Running as admin" || echo "NOT running as admin"`

This relies on the return code of `at` being zero only when running as admin.

Comment: This seems the same method as @Steven gave in earlier answer (which does not seem to work on Windows 8.1 according to a comment - unless MSYS "at" is somehow). While the question was about Cygwin, it is interesting to compare with similar MSYS. Thanks for the contribution.

Comment: Very similar yes. However I ended up on this question trying to use it to check in a script (Win7, Msys) rather than setting the bash prompt style, so I thought this might be of use to someone else doing the same

Comment: I agree on the usefulness.